# Regular expression brackets (), or |, ^ $ are used in combination

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I would like to match a string of numbers, which can be 0, but I do not allow 0 to start.

This is my wording: `^0|[1-9][0-9]*$`.but it will match 01.

This is the result of the search to write: `^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$`.Why do we have to match the brackets after the match is correct.

Comment: `^0$|^[1-9][0-9]*$`

Answer (score 3):

> This is my wording: `^0|[1-9][0-9]*$` but it will match 01.

That's because you are saying, match stuff that starts with a 0, *or* match stuff that ends with `[1-9][0-9]*`

Say the right thing:

`^0$|^[1-9][0-9]*$`

Or, group the alternatives - then ^ and $ will still anchor what is found at the beginning *and* end:

`^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$`